# on select update value in another field with object respont data angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help. I have two values that come from a separate query and tables but are linked together. The one data has an integer value from Table A:

```
{..}
WebDealerType: "1"
```

that I display in the  field, next to it I offer a drop box with other value options that come from Table B:

```
(4) […]
0: Object { DealerTypeID: "1", DealerTypeName: "Vehicle" }
1: Object { DealerTypeID: "2", DealerTypeName: "Recreational" }
2: Object { DealerTypeID: "3", DealerTypeName: "Auctions" }
3: Object { DealerTypeID: "4", DealerTypeName: "Mobility" }
```

This is set in the controller:

```
$scope.product = angular.copy(item); //Table A

Data.get('typeIDInfo').then(function (data) {
    $scope.product.typeID = data.data; //Table B
    console.log(data.data);
});
```

If the user selects a new value from the select box I want to update the newly selected integer value in the `<input>`. My problem is that it is updating it but putting the full object value in the input field instead of just the `product.typeID`.

This is the HTML:

```
<input value="{{product.WebDealerType}}" />
<select ng-model="product.WebDealerType" 
    ng-options="option.DealerTypeID+' -  '+option.DealerTypeName  for option in product.typeID track by option.DealerTypeID" 
    class="form-control" style="width: 200px;display: inline">
</select>
```

This is what it does right now. Image of dropbox:

[image]

Console log after selecting from the Input box:

```
WebDealerType: {…}
DealerTypeID: "4"
DealerTypeName: "Mobility Dealerships"
```

All I want to show and grab from the `<input>` field is the `option.DealerTypeID` value. I am just not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Just so you know, the [angular] tag is for versions of Angular >= 2. This question is clearly for Angular 1.x and should use the [angularjs] tag otherwise people might not find your question.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know did not realize I put the wrong tag on my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to review the ng-options syntax: [AngularJS: API: ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

*select* as *label* for *value* in *array*

Where:

- select = what gets bound to ng-model on selection
- label = what gets displayed to the user
- value = variable for the current array value
- array = the array you're iterating over

So your syntax should be the following:

```
<select ng-model="product.WebDealerType" ng-options="option.DealerTypeID as option.DealerTypeID+' -  '+option.DealerTypeName  for option in product.typeID track by option.DealerTypeID" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;display: inline"></select>
```